# Accessibility compliance of specific table HTML

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

I have an HTML layout engine that has a common component that can switch between ol HTML, ul HTML, and table HTML structure

```
<component>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div> Enter Data here </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div> Enter Data here </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</component>
```

OR

```
<component>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <div> 
                <th>
                    Enter Data here 
                </th>
                <th>
                    Enter Data here 
                </th>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div> 
                <td>
                    Enter Data here 
                </td>
                <td>
                    Enter Data here 
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div> 
                <td>
                    Enter Data here 
                </td>
                <td>
                    Enter Data here 
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</component>
```

I have used WAVE/AXE/Lighthouse to validate the HTML structure of the Table and it seems to be working fine.

Is there any issue if my layout engine creates a few additional divs inside the table HTML?
My layout engine creates a div between the tr and td elements. Are there any issues that can arise from this with respect to accessibility standpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `<table>` structure is valid, which would violate [WCAG 4.1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#parsing).  The [html spec for `<tr>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tr-element) says the content model is "Zero or more td, th, and script-supporting elements", where "script supporting" is defined here, https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-2, which is essentially the `<script>` element.  So having a `<div>` as an immediate child of a `<tr>` is not valid and *could* cause accessibility problems with a screen reader trying to read the table.

Comment: Thanks for the links to reference information!
So I have two follow ups to that:
1. is there any way to suppress the divs within screen readers? aria-hidden or similar attribute?
2. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/table_role)
This is an alternative way to implement Table.
Would below structure be ok?
<div role="table">
<div role="rowgroup">
<div role="row">
**<div>**<div role="cell">enter data </div>**</div>**
</div> 
</div>
</div>

My layout engine can also be converted to paint divs instead of ul/ol/table aswell but with extra divs.

Comment: <div role="table">  
<div role="rowgroup">  
<div role="row">  
**<div>**  
<div role="cell">enter data </div>  
**</div>**  
</div>  
</div>  
</div>

Comment: @ArpitShekhar - your follow-up questions may be sufficiently complex and differentiated from the original question that they warrant a new post...

Comment: @ArpitShekhar, it'd be better if you update your OP with additional information since the posting area has better formatting tools compared to this comment area.  Your code will be easier to read there and then I can update my answer with my thoughts on your update.

Comment: **Question 1**: I'm not sure what you mean by suppressing the `<div>` from the screen reader.  The table code is invalid and is unrelated to screen readers.  It's not a matter of getting screen readers to ignore the `<div>`.  You *can* have elements ignored by screen readers by using `aria-hidden`, but that's irrelevant to the issue of improperly formed html.

Comment: **Question 2**: You absolutely can create a table using non-semantic elements such as `<div>` and `<span>` elements and using all the various table roles (table, row, cell, rowheader, columnheader) but it's a **lot** of work. When possible, use the natively accessible html elements first (`<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, `<th scope="row">`, `<th scope="col">`) but if there's a reason they can't be used, then you can fallback to using **roles**.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up comments and the suggestion to update the OP rather than comments!
for your reply to Q1:
I'm working with a vendor that validates web pages for accessibility and they said having role="none" on the div will make screen readers ignore the div but semantically it is still invalid. It is sort of a workaround not great though.
for Q2:
Agreed on the effort! Wanted to avoid the higher effort and hence was looking of a way to suppress the div itself and still be valid approach.
@AlexanderNied - Will keep in mind the housekeeping rules. A bit new to posting stuff. Thanks

Comment: I'm hoping you mis-heard your vendor. Adding `role="none"` does nothing on a `<div>` because a div is already a non-semantic element. A screen reader can't ignore an element that is already being ignored. Adding the role also doesn't make the table code valid because you can't have a `<div>` as a child of a `<tr>` *unless* the `<div>` has `role="cell"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<div role="row">` instead tag `<tr>`. [Link to Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA) 1.1. Row role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#row)

```
<component>
     <div role="table">
        <div role="row"> 
            <span role="columnheader">
                Enter Data here 
            </span>
            <span role="columnheader">
                Enter Data here 
            </span>
        </div>
        <div role="row"> 
            <span role="cell">
                Enter Data here 
            </span>
            <span role="cell">
                Enter Data here 
            </span>
        </div>
        <div role="row"> 
            <span role="cell">
                Enter Data here 
            </span>
            <span role="cell">
                Enter Data here 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</component>
```

Comment: This was already mentioned in the comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70283401/76714.